# Ajax response undefined How to resolve it?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Json data:

```
[{"id":"1","reg_title":"Mr.","reg_first_name":"shah","reg_last_name":"rushabh","reg_email":"shahrushabh1996@gmail.com","reg_password":"$2y$15$tPAtKlT6VPtmPFRvlIuA0.Xh1IGh\/1.FY09lFXOrzrv3UkrJOFHna","fbid":"","secret_question":"","secret_answer":"","company":"","work_phone_number":"","home_phone_number":"","mobile_phone_number":"","reg_address":"b\/1 rajasthan  Flat","reg_no":"123","reg_country":"India","reg_postal":"380005","reg_city":"Ahmedabad","reg_state":null,"reg_gender":"Male","reg_verifycode":"899884070","reg_active":"Yes","type":"","token":"","image":"","reg_voucher":"","reg_date":"2017-04-18","user_lat":"","user_long":"","newsletteractive":"","showtel":"No","website":""}]
```

I am getting this response when I am calling ajax function. But when I am alerting `response.id` it displaying undefined please help me. How to display data?

Comment: Please post the ajax calling function

Comment: index the array like response[0].id and you are good to go!

Comment: still undefined

Comment: Please post how you are displaying the response after getting the response.

Answer (score 1):

Check the typeof response you are getting. The response you are getting is in the **JSON String** format. When you got the response other than JSON you have to parse the response as JSON.

```
 response = JSON.parse(response);
```

Then you can access **response[index].property** you want.

Answer (score 0):

Because your response is an array you have to tell javascript which item of your array you want to access.

So instead of

```
response.id
```

you have to do something like this

```
response[0].id
```

### Update

```js
var response = [{"id":"1","reg_title":"Mr.","reg_first_name":"shah","reg_last_name":"rushabh","reg_email":"shahrushabh1996@gmail.com","reg_password":"$2y$15$tPAtKlT6VPtmPFRvlIuA0.Xh1IGh\/1.FY09lFXOrzrv3UkrJOFHna","fbid":"","secret_question":"","secret_answer":"","company":"","work_phone_number":"","home_phone_number":"","mobile_phone_number":"","reg_address":"b\/1 rajasthan  Flat","reg_no":"123","reg_country":"India","reg_postal":"380005","reg_city":"Ahmedabad","reg_state":null,"reg_gender":"Male","reg_verifycode":"899884070","reg_active":"Yes","type":"","token":"","image":"","reg_voucher":"","reg_date":"2017-04-18","user_lat":"","user_long":"","newsletteractive":"","showtel":"No","website":""}];

console.log('id:', response[0].id)
console.log('reg_last_name:', response[0].reg_last_name)
console.log('reg_no:', response[0].reg_no)
```

Comment: still undefined

Comment: Can you please check on my website.

Answer (score 0):

since you are hitting ajax service your response will be in object format. You need to convert it into JSON format using 
`var response= $.parseJSON(request);`

then you can able to retrieve its data by putting this json variable in for loop as shown in below code.It will print all records data

```js
var response = [{"id":"1","reg_title":"Mr.","reg_first_name":"shah","reg_last_name":"rushabh","reg_email":"shahrushabh1996@gmail.com","reg_password":"$2y$15$tPAtKlT6VPtmPFRvlIuA0.Xh1IGh\/1.FY09lFXOrzrv3UkrJOFHna","fbid":"","secret_question":"","secret_answer":"","company":"","work_phone_number":"","home_phone_number":"","mobile_phone_number":"","reg_address":"b\/1 rajasthan  Flat","reg_no":"123","reg_country":"India","reg_postal":"380005","reg_city":"Ahmedabad","reg_state":null,"reg_gender":"Male","reg_verifycode":"899884070","reg_active":"Yes","type":"","token":"","image":"","reg_voucher":"","reg_date":"2017-04-18","user_lat":"","user_long":"","newsletteractive":"","showtel":"No","website":""}];

for(i=0;i<response.length;i++)
{
console.log('id:', response[i].id+'  && reg_last_name:', response[i].reg_last_name+'  && reg_no:', response[i].reg_no);

}
```